# How to get the rows based on unique column values of their first occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
col1    col2    col3
 1        A       B
 1        D       R
 2        R       P
 2        D       F
 3        T       G
 1        R       S
 3        R       S
```

I want to get the data frame with first 3 unique value of col1. If some col1 value comes later in the df, it will ignore.

The final data frame should look like:

```
df
col1    col2    col3
 1        A       B
 1        D       R
 2        R       P
 2        D       F
 3        T       G
```

How to do it most efficient way in pandas ?

Comment: @jezrael I want to keep first three unique col1 values, drop_duplicates() doesn't make ant solution, and if its duplicate please give me the link

Comment: This question is different from the drop duplicates one linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper consecutive groups series with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 3
df = df[df.col1.ne(df.col1.shift()).cumsum() <= N]
print (df)
   col1 col2 col3
0     1    A    B
1     1    D    R
2     2    R    P
3     2    D    F
4     3    T    G
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.col1.ne(df.col1.shift()).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    5
Name: col1, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution which stops at once found the three first different values

```
import pandas as pd
data="""
col1    col2    col3
 1        A       B
 1        D       R
 2        R       P
 2        D       F
 3        T       G
 1        R       S
 3        R       S
 """
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
nbr = 3
dico={}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    dico[row.col1]=True
    if len(dico.keys())==nbr:
        df = df[0:index+1]
        break

print(df)

  col1 col2 col3
0     1    A    B
1     1    D    R
2     2    R    P
3     2    D    F
4     3    T    G
```

Comment: @jezrael i dont speak about execution time, but fast in way of found solution.. sorry for my english

Comment: Because last OP sentence is `How to do it most efficient way in pandas ?` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas.DataFrame.duplicated) method in pandas:

```
mask1 = df.duplicated(keep = "first") # this line is to get the first occ.
mask2 = df.duplicated(keep = False)   # this line is to get the row that occ one single time.
mask =  ~mask1 | ~mask2
df[mask]
```